# How can I send an image from an API from a Discord bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

For context, this Discord bot gets a players displayname from the Hypixel API. It then uses the displayname to get an image from the Plancke API: `gen.plancke.io/exp/${player.displayname}.png`

I have been looking for ways of sending this image to a channel and I have found this way of doing it.

```
message.channel.send({files: [`gen.plancke.io/exp/${player.displayname}.png`]});
```

This method works with local files, but I am trying to send an image from an API, which in this case is `gen.plancke.io/exp/${player.displayname}.png`. When I run my code, it gives me an error saying it cannot find the file. How can I send the image from an API instead of a local file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a link to `files` without using `http://` or `https://` will make it assume it's a file path, not a URL, that is why it "cannot find the file".

```js
message.channel.send({files: [`https://gen.plancke.io/exp/${player.displayname}.png`]});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have another question, is there a way to get this image and set it as an embed thumbnail?

Comment: just use the URL in the embed constructor's `.setThumbnail()` method

Comment: how can I do this in python instead?

Answer (score 0):

```js
message.channel.send({ file: `http://gen.plancke.io/exp/${player.displayname}.png` });
```

This should do you justice. Also, errors will be thrown If the user's name is not found on the "API".

```js
message.channel.send({ file: `http://gen.plancke.io/exp/${player.displayname}.png` }).catch(e => {
  console.log("Invalid displayname provided.");
});
```

With this code, the errors will be logged clearly.